# sympathy upvotes revisited : what should I do?

Tags: support, voting

Ok I know there are many many question about it, and I have no problem with closing this one if someone can guide me to the answer I am looking for.

Sometimes, I like to give sympathy-upvotes myself : if I see an answer in minus that has no reason at all to be in minus as far as I am concerned, I upvote.  I must admit I wouldn't upvote it when it was 0.

Eg: s.o. asks something very trivial, like a syntax issue  :

> 'why is 'select * where a > 0 from
>   table'.` not working?

Then I don't even read the answers.  A '-1' however stands out, and when it's correct

> 'you should check your syntax, where
>   clause comes last''

I undo than the -1 because there's no need for it.

Maybe a bad example , but in cases where I think the answer doesnot deserve a minus, but in my opinion neither qualifies for an upvote, what should i do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your vote should not be dependent on what other people before you have voted.

Here is an example:

1. Someone answers a question poorly.
2. They get down-voted.
3. They quickly correct the answer to not be so somewhat decent.
4. You view the question and see the -1 with a somewhat decent answer and upvote it to 0.
5. The down-voter comes back and sees that the answerer fixed the problem and removes the downvote.
6. Now the answerer now has a +1 score on something that you won't not have upvoted if it was zero when you saw it.

There are other cases, serial down-votes that might get wiped away, etc.

I would just realize that a down vote is not that horrible of a thing.  One upvote on a post makes up for 5 down-votes, so even someone with a score of -3 that had 4 down and one upvote is still rising is rep.

Comment: Very well explained. +1

Comment: Even worse: kind of *expecting* pity upvotes sometimes stops me from downvoting while, for example, downvoting on questions [is quite important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294).

Comment: +1 since very claer, but what to do than with a question that is googleable and therefore, falsly so, gets downvotes?  Neither upvote that?

Comment: I have given it some thought, and I guess you are right. That's to say : most right as possible in this difficult matter.  I will act accordingly from now one, tx.

Answer (score -2):

IMO when you see such posts which are negative and **do not deserve the negative votes**, then you can just do your bit by upvoting ofcourse. In addition to that, you can leave a comment in that post about why you feel this post does not deserve to be in negative vote.

If more users feel that you are correct, then probably they will add more upvotes, also the downvoters possibly will read your comments and revert too.

Apart from this, there is nothing much you can do about such things.

Comment: Yes, but there you get the effect that if they neiter deserve upvotes, they end up with like 40rep instead of 0.